# como visualizar un excel en una tabla html?, y luego enviarlo a mi base de datos

Tags: javascript, html5, excel

Buen dia comunidad, quiero hacer que los excel que dan pasarlo a visulizar en una tabla html para luego guardarlo en la base de datos, busque en varios foros, pero no encuentro, supongo que para visualizar el excel debo usar javascript y para enviarlo a la base de datos necesito php, alguien me podria ayudar? se lo agradeceria mucho, estoy que busco y busco y solo encontre esto, pero no me funciona. https://redstapler.co/sheetjs-tutorial-convert-excel-html-table/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
    $('#input-excel').change(function(e){
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
        var wb = XLSX.read(data,{type:'array'});
        var htmlstr = XLSX.write(wb,{sheet:"Hoja1", type:'binary',bookType:'html'});
        $('#wrapper')[0].innerHTML += htmlstr;
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx@0.14.1/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar"><span>Leer Excel </span></div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <input type="file" id="input-excel"/>
  </div>
```

Si te fijas lo que debes hacer es declarar el nombre de la hoja a leer, en este caso es **Hoja1**, modifica de acuerdo a tu excel.

Suponiendo el siguiente excel:

[image: ejemplo excel]

si te fijas el nombre de la hoja es **Hoja1**, bien ahora el resultado:
[image: result]

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

es muy importante el nombre de la hoja mas no del archivo..!!

Comment: para obtener estos datos y enviarlos a mysql debes usar algo de javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23770671/5215609

Comment: gracias, me funciona 100% pero como los capturo y los guardo a mi base de datos?, estoy usando php.

Comment: dime como lo hago con un botton, osea cargo el archivo y luego presiono el boton y se muestra la tabla